# Spawn multiple enemies and get info when bullet hits

Tags: python, object, pygame

I'm trying to spawn multiple enemies, but I just can't get it to work... Need some help please, I'm using groups as you might see. 
Also I want to get info on when a projectile hits a target, I googled and found a way to make the enemies and bullets to disappear, but I want to get the info stored in a variable when it happend, but I don't know how. 
It's this line of code:

```py
enemy_hit = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(projectiles, enemies, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
```

The code underneath is the full code I have used, as I wrote previously, I want to spawn multiple enemies.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.images = self.one, self.two, self.three, = pygame.image.load("pictures\SpaceShip\one.png"), pygame.image.load("pictures\SpaceShip\\two.png"), pygame.image.load("pictures\SpaceShip\\three.png")
        self.image = self.one
        self.imageCount = 1
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (512, 630))
        self.speed = 4
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(81,80))

    def nextpicture(self):
        if self.imageCount == 1:
            self.image = self.one
            self.imageCount = 2
        elif self.imageCount == 2:
            self.image = self.two
            self.imageCount = 3
        elif self.imageCount == 3:
            self.image = self.three
            self.imageCount = 1
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(81,80))

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("pictures\shot.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (player.rect.x+41, 610))
        self.speed = 4

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.kill()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("pictures\Enemy_Ufo.png")
        self.speed = 1
        self.y = 200
        self.x = 200
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x,self.y))
        self.hit = False
    def __add__(self):
        self.x += 100
    def spawn(self):
        self.x = self.x + 100

    def death(self):
        pass

size = width, height = 1024, 768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = 5, 7, 37
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()
projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
icon = pygame.image.load('pictures\SpaceShip\SpaceShip_LowRez.png')
counter = 0
enemyCount = 0
for i in range(5):
    enemies.add(Enemy())
    print(Enemy().x)
    enemy.__add__()

run = True
while run:
    enemy_hit = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(projectiles, enemies, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    for hit in enemy_hit:
        enemies.add(Enemy())

    clock.tick(120)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_UP) and len(projectiles) == 0:
              projectiles.add(Projectile())



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) == True and player.rect.x != width-80:
        player.rect.x += player.speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]) == True and player.rect.x != 0:
        player.rect.x -= player.speed

    for projectile in projectiles:
        projectile.move()

    #Changes picture of the ship
    counter += 1
    if counter/4 == 1:
        player.nextpicture()
    if counter == 20:
        counter = 0

    enemy.death()
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
    screen.fill(background)
    projectiles.draw(screen)
    enemies.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter for the x coordinate to the constructor of the class `Enemy`:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x=200):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("pictures\Enemy_Ufo.png")
        self.speed = 1
        self.y = 200
        self.x = x
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x,self.y))
        self.hit = False
```

Create enemies at random positions by the use of [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```py
for i in range(5):
    enemies.add(Enemy(random.randint(0, width)))
```

Increment a `score` when an enemy was hit and use the [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) (or even [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module) to show the current score:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
score = 0

run = True
while run:

    # [...]

    enemy_hit = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(projectiles,enemies,True,pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    for hit in enemy_hit:
        enemies.add(Enemy(random.randint(0, width)))
        score += 1

    # [...]

    screen.fill(background)

    text = font.render(str(score), False, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text, (20, 20))

    projectiles.draw(screen)
    enemies.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.flip()
```